# How to read two json objects in spring boot controller

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot

I am new to java, i am trying to pass two json objects from ajax call to controller class... but i am getting below exception

```
Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public java.lang.String com.controllers.EmployeeController.saveData(java.lang.String,com.entities.EmployeeData,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
```

Jquery Code:

```
$("#saveData").submit(function(event) {          
    var data = [];
    var formData = {};
    var myJsonString;       
    var slab, lower;
    $("table tbody tr").each(function(index) {
        //alert(index);
       slab = $(this).find('.slab').val();
       lower = $(this).find('.lower').val();
      if(slab != undefined && lower != undefined){
        var form1 =new Object();
    form1.slab=slab;
    form1.lower=lower;
    data.push(form1);
      }         
    });
    var form = this;
    event.preventDefault();      
        $.each(this, function(i, v){
        var input = $(v);      
        formData[input.attr("name")] = input.val();
        });
    var url = "/Portal/SaveData";       
    ajaxCall(url,formData,data);

});
function ajaxCall(url,formData,data){   
    //alert("AjaxPost!!!"+url);
    // DO POST
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url : url,
        data : JSON.stringify({formData:formData,value:data}),
        dataType : 'json',
        beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
        success : function(response) {
            alert("Success");
            }else{          
                alert("else");
            }               
        },
        error : function(e) {
            bootbox.alert({ 
                  size: "small",
                  title: "ALERT",                   
                  message: "There seems to be some problem while Proccessing record!"
                })

        }
    });
}
```

Controller Method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/SaveData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String saveData(@RequestBody String value,@Valid @RequestBody EmployeeData emp, BindingResult result) {
System.out.println(" Creating!!!");
//logic here
}
```

Where is the mistake in ajax call or in controller file?
 there is any other way to pass multiple json objects to controller class file?

Answer (score 0):

The @RequestBody annotation is expected to map to one and only one parameter in your method and to contain the entire contents of the incoming request.

You should map all your form data into a single JSON object, then handle that as a single JSON object in the backend as well.